# In Rails 3.2 & Rspec 2, how to manage a set of 50,000 pairs of input_string, expected_score pairs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am writing specs for a method 'scores' a string of text according to a fairly complex set of rules having to do with a large set of various combinations of keywords.

My test set of strings is 50,000 strings. `my_method_being_tested("some test string")` produce a score with 3 elements `[boolean, boolean, integer]`.

I have a tally of 50,000 inputs & expected outputs, something like this

```
test_set = [ {"test string one" => [true, false, 0] } , { "test string 2" => [false, false, 10] } , ... ]
```

What is the best way to store/manage a 50,000 element test set when using Rspec, so I can loop thru the array something like:

```
test_set.each do | a_set |
 my_method_being_tested(a_set.key).should == a_set.value
end
```

There is no underlying ActiveRecord Model for the method in my app so I cannot simply store a fixture and load it into an activerecord table (unless perhaps it makes sense somehow to create an activerecord-less model of some kind and load a fixture into that?

Comment: How are your test set and expected results currently stored?

Answer (score 0):

StackOverflow isn't really set up for answering "what is best" questions, but your basic approach is fine and you just need to make sure that your data structure and access mechanisms match up. Given the  code snippets you showed, I would suggest reading up on Ruby hashes and structs.

At a meta level you'd have:

```
test_set = my_test_setup
test_set.each do |pair|
  expect(my_method_being_tested(my_key_accessor(pair)).to match_array(my_value_accessor(pair))
end
```

If you want to keep `test_set` as as is, then you can change your test loop to be:

```
test_set.each do |pair|
  expect(my_method_being_tested(pair.keys.first)).to match_array(pair.values.first)
end
```

If you want to keep your test loop as is, you can change our test_setup to be:

```
TestPair = Struct.new(:key, :value)
test_set = [
  TestPair.new("test string one", [true, false, 0]),
  TestPair.new("test string 2", [false, false, 10]),
  ... ]
```

Note that I'm using the new "expect" syntax rather than the deprecated "should" syntax, but that's a separate issue.

UPDATE: As for storing key/value pairs in a file, there are myriad options as well. YAML, as you note in your comment is fine, and you can combine it with DBM, letting you do something like:

```
require 'yaml/dbm'

YAML::DBM.load('your_yaml_file.yml').each do |key, value|
  expect(my_method_being_tested(key)).to match_array(value)
end
```

That, of course, assumes that you've stored your key/value pairs in the YAML+DBM file in the first place, which gets you back to creating some Ruby to represent the key/value pairs.

A set of 50k items isn't that big to keep in memory, but if you're really concerned about doing the reading and testing of each pair incrementally, you can always read a line at a time from a file. But that still begs the question of what to store in that line (e.g. JSON) and formatting it in the first place.

Comment: Thank you although my question is really intended to ask if there is a way store a (large amount) of test data in a yaml file or perhaps a activerecord-less model of some kind, as opposed to actually storing the test data in the ruby code in the spec.